# How do I fwrite and fread array of strings to file?

Tags: c, arrays, io, fwrite, fread

I want to fwrite an array of strings to a file. Right now, I write first the number of strings in the array, followed by the array using this code:

```
int rows = 3;
char **c = calloc (rows,sizeof(char*));
c[0] = "cat\0";
c[1] = "dog\0";
c[2] = "mouse\0";

FILE * f = fopen("test", "w");
if (f) {
    fwrite(&rows, sizeof(int), 1, f);
    fwrite(c, sizeof(char*), rows, f);
}
fclose(f);
```

When I read the data back in, I get an empty char**. Here is my code:

```
FILE * f = fopen("test", "r");
    if (f) {
        int num = -99;
        fread(&num, sizeof(int), 1, f);
        char** buff = malloc(num*sizeof(char*));
        fread(buff, sizeof(char), num, f);

        buff[num] = 0x00;

        for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            printf("%s ", buff[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

Comment: You write/read an array of pointers. This is almost never a good idea.

Comment: @Olaf Should I instead write each string by itself instead of an array?

Comment: You haven't allocated space for each string on the input side.  You aren't writing them correctly on the output side.  You'll need to write each string separately.  You should check the contents of the file using external tools (e.g. `od` or `xxd` or some other data dumping program) before trying to read the data.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler is there a way to write an array instead of each string separately?

Comment: You'd have to store the strings in contiguous memory and write the relevant section of the contiguous memory in a single operation.  You'll need to know how long that space is, too.  It can be done, but it is modestly hard work.

Comment: Basically yes, but you also have to allocate memory on read. Pointers are not arrays! Alternatively you could use a 2D array, but that would be a waste of memory (and might have other issues, e.g. a max. string length).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only write the address of variable `c` to file '`test`' (by function `fwrite(c,sizeof...)`). Why don't you write the value into the file?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon.  This answer is not entirely accurate.  The code writes three pointers to the file.  It doesn't write the strings, and writing pointers to a file is seldom constructive as you can't read the pointer value back again and use it — the address is likely to be invalid.  Also, this is almost as much comment as answer.  I know you can't make comments yet, but it is usually best to bide your time, providing good answers and not trying to make comments until you have enough reputation to be allowed to do so.

Comment: Thank you,i'm a newbie so lacking experience, i will improve this and hope  that you can still guide me further.